# Run two JARS sequentially one after another using a BATCH file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jar, batch-processing

I need to execute 2 jars files in sequence order.  number1.jar need to run and finish its execution before number2.jar is executed.

How could I achieve this using a BATCH file under a Windows environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
REM Run first and finish ...
java -jar number1.jar

REM .. then start number two.
java -jar number2.jar
```